# Android Studio 4.0 stuck refreshing, can't run project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I just upgraded my Android Studio from 3.7 to 4.0. After upgrading, I changed the gradle dependency to 0.7.+ as indicated in the release notes. 
Now, the IDE is stuck with a background task that says it is "Refreshing" my project. 
I cannot run the project or do anything as those gets queued behind this task.

Note: it did a maven central update of about 100 MB before which completed successfully.

Comment: Anything interesting in your log file (Help menu > Show log)

Comment: I got it resolved. Basically went back to the build.gradle, changed it back to 0.6.+ restarted Android Studio. It complained about the gradle version so I let it fix to 0.7.+. Clicked the "Sync Project with Gradle Files", took a bit then worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is how I resolved it

### Step 1: Modify `build.gradle`

Open the `build.gradle` in your module (not the top-level `build.gradle` file)
Change the following (or something similar

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

Save.

### Step 2: Restart Android Studio

### Step 3: Fix build.gradle

Android Studio will nag you about Gradle version. Let it fix it. (You ***might*** have to manually change it to 0.7.+).
Click on `Sync Project with Gradle Files` then gradle will download the dependencies and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### I fixed it too.

1. change project level build.gradle classpath from 0.7 to 0.6
2. restart the android studio
3. import module and notice me to upgrade build.gradle version and change 0.6 to 0.7 manually and downloading maven resource successfully.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the version I have is 1.3.0. Why this issue still happens after so much time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just updated my android studio to 2.0 on ubuntu 14.04. This issue arose for one of the project and it was solved through a [answer][1] here which seems unrelated to this problem !!

If you are using Android Studio 2.0 Beta, this issue might appear (more likely if you are working on NTFS filesystem) and it seems like the "Instant Run" is the culprit. Search for "Instant Run" in settings and uncheck the box

Posting here to an old question - maybe somebody else might me  stuck on this aswell.